# Maximum voltage/current on a passive 8 ohm buzzer

Tags: audio, pwm, buzzer

I have a buzzer with:

- 8 ohm
- 1 watt rated power
- Resonant frequency: 700/600 Hz

In order to make it sound, should I apply a PWM with 700/600 Hz, and turning ON and OFF?

What is the maximum voltage? Can I use 12VDC PWM?

Comment: The friendly datasheet ought to tell you this. Although it may assume that the reader is aware of the uttermost basics of electronics such as P=UI, U=IR etc.

Answer (score 2):

12V into 8 ohms is 1.5 amps.

That's 18W. Assuming you drive a 0V/12v square wave to speaker, it only sees 18W half the time and 0W for the other half.

That's still 9W.

No, 12V is not OK if the device has mac power of 1W.

You can now use Ohm's law to calculate max voltage being somewhere around 2.8V for 1W.

Comment: So should I add in between a transistor and a resistor? to limitate voltage and current ?

12Vdc -> resistor -> buzzer -> NPN Collector  ?

Comment: A current-limiting-resistor *and* a series-connected coupling capacitor. The capacitor blocks DC that would otherwise heat the buzzer wastefully (DC doesn't produce sound).

Comment: @glen_geek We don't really know what OP means with a buzzer. Buzzers that take in DC and buzz themselves do exist. The capacitor in series would not work then.

Comment: @Justme Correctly cautious. "8-ohms" combined with "1-watt" combined with "passive" suggests a passive electrodynamic loudspeaker. But "buzzer" often refers to an active device that requires DC power...or even a vibrator-type motor. I'm guessing that the term "buzzer" has been in-cautiously applied.

Comment: This is the item: https://www.visaton.de/en/products/drivers/miniature-speakers/k-28-wp-8-ohm

Comment: @da_bb That is a normal speaker. Sensitivity is 75dB SPL at 1W power and at 1 meter distance. It depends what you are doing of course, but 75 dB is a lot of SPL. The speaker can handle 2W though.

Comment: ok but is the power assumption the same ? so I cannot connect it directly to 12Vdc PWM  ?

Answer (score 0):

12V will fry it.  The power dissipated by a constant 12V would be 12²/8 = 18W.  Assuming the PWM signal is only on half the time, that's still 9W, way over the rated power of the buzzer.